# I would like to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test in Jamovi

Tags: anova, likert, kruskal-wallis-test, binning, jamovi

My problem is that I have data of sexual assertiveness (7 point Likert-scale, SAQ) and relationship satisfaction (5 point Likert-scale, RAS) but I would like to divide the sexual assertiveness variable into 3 groups: low, medium, and high sexual assertiveness. This is because my hypothesis is that people characterized by higher sexual assertiveness are also characterized by higher relationship satisfaction. I thought that the 3 groups could be done with quartiles, but I don't know how to make this happen in order to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test in Jamovi.

Comment: I find it difficult to respond to this question. I am a bit confused by two aspects. **1** What is exactly not working. Are you asking how to transform a variable or how to perform a Kruskal-Wallis test (for this you could better search for instructions on how yo use jamovi). **2** and what is disturbing me while thinking about the first point is that there are much better ways to test the hypothesis than a Kruskal-Wallis test, and that it is not neccesary to downscale your data from 7 classes to 3 classes. How about fitting a model and test it with goodness of fit (like chi-squared)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last point about using a chi-squared test. Based off the wording, these seem to be composite tests rather than individual Likert-scale items (the SAQ and RAS).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't immediately clear to me why you would convert an already measured composite test into an arbitrarily defined three-level factor (hint: you shouldn't). It seems implied by your wording that you already have an IV of sexual assertiveness and a DV of relationship satisfaction. So I would model that with the given measures you already have rather than arbitrarily binning people into groups (this comes at an unnecessary amount of information loss, see reference below).

If you are using the composite scores of [SAQ](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00224499.2014.944970?casa_token=j2NXmQ8hMOkAAAAA%3AQojnx38XO2bCEUxLsr2dH7kv5zwTaTfclipfnG2CdTMiB1dhwBoS3P3o8OnpCQ6PWPNKCI5R6I5cYY0) and [RAS](https://www.jstor.org/stable/352430?casa_token=zcHciWlpxIwAAAAA%3A1EA1OGpm_hP-ae52rPP3YPtgB2HY9szNAY09uIF8Jh9dE7wCRwIRInuTh5ThOtZQJ67YkFre4ERh-o9hPtK9PnqT7bzjRwxi5_8nz4yNC_al3qR4IPTdJA&seq=2), then any of your typical regression modeling techniques would work here (though attention would need to be paid to how the residuals are defined depending on how people respond to this composite in the literature). Of course, because of the inherent imprecision of Likert-scale tests, you would need to account for inter-item reliability to define any uncertainty in the estimated composites (using measures like Cronbach's alpha or McDonald's omega).

##### Reference

Royston, P., Altman, D. G., & Sauerbrei, W. (2006). Dichotomizing continuous predictors in multiple regression: A bad idea. Statistics in Medicine, 25, 127–141. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.2331